# Why I cannot use an array with a set in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

Consider the following example:

```
let set = new Set()
set.add([3, 6])
```

If I attempt to use `set.has([3, 6])` I expect to receive a `true` but I got a `false`, why?

Comment: The same reason that `[3, 6] == [3, 6]` returns false.

Comment: Why?, I genuinely want to know, and how can I avoid it in this case?

Comment: Arrays are not compared by contents. They're compared as objects, they're only equal if they're the same object.

Comment: `Set.has` uses an equality check to compare items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing arrays in ES6 Set and accessing them by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760644/storing-arrays-in-es6-set-and-accessing-them-by-value)

Comment: So, as alternative I can store an object?, coming from low-level languages iterate an array lineary looks pretty inefficient