# Javascript: How do I check if an array contains exactly another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have arrays parent and child. I want to check if a child exists inside a parent array. The ordering matters.
Example:

```
parent = ["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
child = ["a", "b", "c"]
//returns true
```

Example:
When parent has a different order:

```
parent = ["x", "g", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a"]
child = ["a", "b", "c"]
//It should return false
```

How would I achieve this in Javascript?
Edit: I have tried this [How to check if an array contains another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661287/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-another-array) but it did not work for my case

Comment: You can `join` 2 array and use parent.`indexOf`(child) > -1

Comment: before asking how to do something on stackoverflow, please tell us what you have already tried. We are not a code writing service, you have to try something, and then ask for help

Comment: You're asking us to di the work for you...
What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661287/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-another-array. It didn't work

Comment: @JDuh That’s not the same situation at all. You’re searching for sub-arrays, not for array elements that are arrays. Do you also need to check whether the items in the “child” array follow one another in the “parent” array? I.e. is `["a", "b", "x", "c"]` a valid “parent” for `["a", "b", "c"]`?

Comment: @Tan nope, that's not really right. Consider https://jsfiddle.net/x1f6x6jn/ (logs "found").

Comment: @JDuh You can tick the answer if it was really helpful to you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can run a loop for `child` and change the index accordingly. You can also use a `match` variable to detect change in the sequence.

**RETURN TRUE**

```js
var parent = ["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
var child = ["a", "b", "c"];

var initIndex = parent.indexOf(child[0]);
var match = true;
for(var i=1; i<child.length; i++){
  var varIndex = parent.indexOf(child[i]);
  if( varIndex === initIndex+1){
    initIndex = varIndex;
    continue;
  }
  match = false;
}

console.log(match);
```

**RETURN FALSE**

```js
var parent = ["x", "g", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a"]
var child = ["a", "b", "c"];

var initIndex = parent.indexOf(child[0]);
var match = true;
for(var i=1; i<child.length; i++){
  var varIndex = parent.indexOf(child[i]);
  if( varIndex === initIndex+1){
    initIndex = varIndex;
    continue;
  }
  match = false;
}

//return false
console.log(match);
```

**USING STRING OPERATION**

You can also convert the array to string to avoid those loop:

```js
var parent = ["x", "g", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a"]
var child = ["a", "b", "c"]

var parentStr = parent.toString();
var match = parentStr.indexOf(child.toString()) !== -1;
//return false
console.log(match);

parent = ["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
child = ["a", "b", "c"]

parentStr = parent.toString();
match = parentStr.indexOf(child.toString()) !== -1;
//return true
console.log(match);
```

Comment: The first approach doesn’t work for repeating elements. The second approach doesn’t work for elements that contain commas.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to string by using `JSON.stringify()` and remove the square brackets from child string.

Now check the `indexOf` child in parent to check if it contains the child.

```js
let parent = ["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
let child = ["a", "b", "c"];
var parStr = JSON.stringify(parent);
var chldStr = JSON.stringify(child).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

console.log(parStr.indexOf(chldStr) !== -1);
```

Comment: Instead of using `JSON.stringify()` and then replace the "array" part... use `.join()`

Comment: @Andreas No. This will fail if the array elements contain commas. The JSON approach is more robust as it guarantees valid JSON delimiters and quote escaping.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function for this a while back that takes some paramenters:

```js
Array.prototype.containsArray = function (child, orderSensitivity, caseSensitivity, typeSensitivity) {
    var self = this;
    if (orderSensitivity) return orderSensitiveComparer();
    else return orderInsensitiveComparer();

    function orderSensitiveComparer() {
        var resultArry = [],
            placeholder = 0;
        if (child.length > self.length) return false;
        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
            for (var k = placeholder; k < self.length; k++) {
                if (equalityComparer(self[k], child[i])) {
                    resultArry.push(true);
                    if (resultArry.length === child.length) return true;
                    placeholder = k + 1;
                    break;
                }
                else resultArry = [];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    function orderInsensitiveComparer() {
        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
            var childHasParentElement = false;
            for (var k = 0; k < self.length; k++) {
                if (equalityComparer(child[i], self[k])) {
                    childHasParentElement = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!childHasParentElement) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function equalityComparer(a, b) {

        if (caseSensitivity && typeSensitivity) return caseSensitiveEq(a, b) && typeSensitiveEq(a, b);
        else if (!caseSensitivity && typeSensitivity) return caseInsensitiveEq(a, b) && typeSensitiveEq(a, b);
        else if (caseSensitivity && !typeSensitivity) return caseSensitiveEq(a, b) && typeInsensitiveEq(a, b);
        else if (!caseSensitivity && !typeSensitivity) return caseInsensitiveEq(a, b) && typeInsensitiveEq(a, b);
        else throw "Unknown set of parameters";


        function caseSensitiveEq(a, b) {
            return a == b;
        }
        function caseInsensitiveEq(a, b) {
            return (a + "").toLowerCase() == (b + "").toLowerCase();
        }
        function typeSensitiveEq(a, b) {
            return typeof(a) === typeof(b);
        }
        function typeInsensitiveEq(a, b) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

var parent = [1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c"];
var child = [1, 2, 3];
var child2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
var child3 = ["A", "b", "C"];
var child4 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var child5 = ["c", "b", "a"];


// Tests:
console.log(parent.containsArray(parent));
console.log(parent.containsArray(child));
console.log(parent.containsArray(child2));

// parent to child 2, order sensitive, not case, not type. => true.
console.log(parent.containsArray(child2, true, false, false));

// parent to child 2, order, not case, type. => false. b/c of type.
console.log(parent.containsArray(child2, true, false, true));

// parent to child 3, order, not case, type. => true.
console.log(parent.containsArray(child3, true, false, true));

// parent to child 4, order, case and type => true.
console.log(parent.containsArray(child4, true, true, true));

// parent to child 4, not order, case and type. => true.
console.log(parent.containsArray(child4, false, true, true));

// parent to child 5, not order case or type => true.
console.log(parent.containsArray(child5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var parent = ["x", "g", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a"]
var child = ["a", "b", "c"]

if(parent.join("").search(child.join("")) === -1) {
    console.log("Not found");
} else {
    console.log("found")
}
```

Comment: This will fail sometimes.

Comment: In which case,?

Comment: If I remember my JavaScript correctly, `parent = ["a,b", "c"]; child = ["a", "b", "c"];` ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple method for small sized arrays of this problem.

1. First join the array to a string, see [Array/join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
2. Search substring, see [String/indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
parent = ["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
child = ["a", "b", "c"];
function matchSubArray(parent, child) {
    parentStr = parent.join('');
    childStr = child.join('');
    return parentStr.indexOf(childStr) != -1;
}
matchSubArray(parent, child);
```

Comment: If you want more good performance, see details like `strstr` of c, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c

Comment: This doesn’t work. `[ "abc" ]` isn’t a subarray of `[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]`.