# How can I check if an array includes another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried to use Array.includes but this code returns false:

```
var list = [[0, 0], [0, 1]]
list.includes([0, 0])
```

Does anyone know what I can use instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an array contains another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661287/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-another-array)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript/29447130

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript search array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315180/javascript-search-array-of-arrays)