# JavaScript - find index of array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the index of an array inside another array in Javascript, as below:

```js
const piece = [5, 10];
const array = [[5, 10], [5, 11]];

//Using indexOf
console.log(array.indexOf(piece));

//Using findIndex
console.log(array.findIndex(function(element) {
  return element == piece;
  }));
```

I'm expecting these to return a 0 as that is the index where my "piece" is inside the larger array, but both methods return `-1`

Any ideas why this is happening? And if there is a different way for me to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: They are different arrays that happen to have the same numbers, but still different arrays.

Comment: Please follow the link to see a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34170710/1635742

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare the actual values you can use the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method:

```js
piece = [5, 10];
array = [[5, 10], [5, 11]];

//Using findIndex
console.log(array.findIndex(function(element) {
    return JSON.stringify(element) == JSON.stringify(piece);
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing objects (arrays) that were created each on their own, so they are not the same objects. If you want, you can compare each of the integers inside the arrays, and when also the array lengths match, you can conclude they are the "same":

```js
piece = [5, 10];
array = [[5, 10], [5, 11]];

//Using findIndex
console.log(array.findIndex(function(element) {
  return element.length === array.length 
      && element.every((val, i) => val == piece[i]);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript are not compared by value, but by reference. So if you have arrays a and b like this:

```
const a = [1, 2];
const b = [1, 2];
```

When you compare them using ==, or === then their references are compared, not values. So this `console.log(a == b)`, or `console.log(a === b)` will print false.